# K-means example(tf.expand_dims)

Tags: tensorflow, k-means

In Example code of Kmeans of Tensorflow,

When use the function 'tf.expand_dims'(Inserts a dimension of 1 into a tensor's shape.) in point_expanded, centroids_expanded 
before calculate tf.reduce_sum.

why is these have different indexes(0, 1) in second parameter?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
points_n = 200
clusters_n = 3
iteration_n = 100
points = tf.constant(np.random.uniform(0, 10, (points_n, 2)))
centroids = tf.Variable(tf.slice(tf.random_shuffle(points), [0, 0],[clusters_n, -1]))
points_expanded = tf.expand_dims(points, 0)
centroids_expanded = tf.expand_dims(centroids, 1)
distances = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(points_expanded, centroids_expanded)), 2)
assignments = tf.argmin(distances, 0)
means = []
for c in range(clusters_n):
    means.append(tf.reduce_mean(tf.gather(points,tf.reshape(tf.where(tf.equal(assignments, c)), [1, -1])), reduction_indices=[1]))
new_centroids = tf.concat(means,0)
update_centroids = tf.assign(centroids, new_centroids)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for step in range(iteration_n):
    [_, centroid_values, points_values, assignment_values] = sess.run([update_centroids, centroids, points, assignments])
    print("centroids" + "\n", centroid_values)
plt.scatter(points_values[:, 0], points_values[:, 1], c=assignment_values, s=50, alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(centroid_values[:, 0], centroid_values[:, 1], 'kx', markersize=15)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to subtract each centroid from each point. First, make sure you understand the notion of broadcasting (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)
 that is linked from tf.subtract (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/subtract). Then, you just need to draw the shapes of `points`, `expanded_points`, `centroids`, and `expanded_centroids` and understand what values get "broadcast" where. Once you do that you will see that broadcasting allows you to compute exactly what you want - subtract each point from each centroid.

As a sanity check, since there are 200 points, 3 centroids, and each is 2D, we should have 200*3*2 differences. This is exactly what we get:

```
In [53]: points
Out[53]: <tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=(200, 2) dtype=float64>

In [54]: points_expanded
Out[54]: <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_4:0' shape=(1, 200, 2) dtype=float64>

In [55]: centroids
Out[55]: <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 2) dtype=float64_ref>

In [56]: centroids_expanded
Out[56]: <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_5:0' shape=(3, 1, 2) dtype=float64>

In [57]: tf.subtract(points_expanded, centroids_expanded)
Out[57]: <tf.Tensor 'Sub_5:0' shape=(3, 200, 2) dtype=float64>
```

If you are having trouble drawing the shapes, you can think of broadcasting the `expanded_points` with dimension `(1, 200, 2)` to dimension `(3, 200, 2)` as copying the 200x2 matrix 3 times along the first dimension. The 3x2 matrix in `centroids_expanded` (of shape (3, 1, 2)) get copied 200 times along the second dimension.

Comment: Thank u for nice explanation